# SwiftMailer connection established error

Tags: email, gmail, swiftmailer

I have problem with sending mails. I using SwiftMailer 5.1.0 and account on gmail, smtp port 465 and openssl is enable, but I have this error:

```
Serwer: smtp.gmail.com:465 ssl
From: BizIn - system mailowy <isystemnew.pcet@gmail.com>
To: test7771@test.pl
Mail debug: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

At my localhost everything is okey and mails are send. But on serwer I have error.

Localhost using PHP in version 5.4.31, but at server is 5.6.0.

Comment: This solved my problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113860/error-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-in-larav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113860/error-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-in-larav)

Answer (score 6):

The fix here solved it for me: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544

@if-joerch
if-joerch commented on Nov 3, 2014

> If you are using PHP 5.6, the error does occur because of the "SSL
>   context options" used for the stream context in swiftmailer. IN PHP
>   5.6 verify_peer and verify_peer_name the default was set to TRUE, so PHP checks the SSL certificate. It is currently not possible to
>   disable it in swiftmailer using some options.
>
> You could disable the SSL check by modifying the function
>   "_establishSocketConnection" in StreamBuffer.php. Add these lines
>   before stream_socket_client command:
>
> ```
> $options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
> $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
> ```
>
> It would be great if these options could be set without hacking the
>   code.

Comment: \vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php