# I cannot send mail with SwiftMailer or PHPMailer from Localhost using gmail

Tags: email, gmail, localhost, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I have recently been unable to send out mails through php on localhost. I use `PHPMailer` and `SwiftMailer` in different parts of the application.

With `SwiftMailer` I get this:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

With `PHPMailer`, the message is:

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

My settings on SwiftMailer look like this:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
->setUsername(APP_GMAIL_EMAIL)
->setPassword(APP_GMAIL_PWD);
```

I have gone through several threads here at SO and elsewhere, and tried many 'fixes' but the error messages remain the same. Some "solutions" I've tried are:

1. Enable OpenSSL in`php.ini` (It was previously off)
2. Change `smtp.gmail.com` to `smtp.googlemail.com`
3. Replace `smtp.gmail.com` with certain gmail IP addresses
4. Replace `smtp.gmail.com` with `gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com')`
5. Add `->setSourceIp('0.0.0.0')` to the instantiation code above, after `setUsername` and `setPassword`

This code was previously working, and I'm not sure what could have broken the function. As part of troubleshooting, I have just confirmed that a similar code on Linux shared hosting is emailing satisfactorily, suggesting that the problem is somehow from my environment. Thus, I even tried different sources of internet access, in case it's an ISP thing.

How can I crack this nut?

Comment: Read the [PHPMailer troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to overcome the problem, at least with `SwiftMailer`. The solution must have arisen after my PHP upgrade from 5.2.5 to 5.6, which is the version I have currently. The insight came from this page:

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544

> If you are using PHP 5.6, the error does occur because of the "SSL
>   context options" used for the stream context in swiftmailer. IN PHP
>   5.6 verify_peer and verify_peer_name the default was set to TRUE, so PHP checks the SSL certificate. It is currently not possible to
>   disable it in swiftmailer using some options.
>
> You could disable the SSL check by modifying the function
>   "_establishSocketConnection" in StreamBuffer.php. Add these lines
>   before stream_socket_client command:

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE; 
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

> It would be great if these options could be set without hacking the
>   code.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448735/2554788 who first pointed me to the said post.

By the way, the path to `StreamBuffer.php` is:

```
\lib\classes\Swift\Transport
```

A word of warning though: this solution is based on hacking the code inside a class, and will probably fail, say, after upgrading `SwiftMailer` versions (in which case you'd need to go back and hack the code again).

Perhaps, more current versions of `SwiftMailer` have put their acts together in PHP 5.6 (I use SwiftMailer 5.1 currently). I intend to try an upgrade ASAP, hoping there has been an elegant fix for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ifedi Okonkwo. The solution helped me.