# Error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ssl, laravel-5, email-verification

Actually,I want to redirect my user to the email verification page after signup process and asking him/her to enter the verification code sent to his/her email. I will be glad if you tell me the process or recommend me any tutorial.

I have already made my working authentication system . I have searched a lot on internet but all i can find is the requirement of laravel auth which i am not using.

On signing up I am getting the error:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

If you need to see my code , just tell me. I'll post it.

UserController.php: http://laravel.io/bin/nQreq
Routes.php:http://laravel.io/bin/JxjNB

Comment: You're connecting to an SSL server that your system doesn't recognize. Self-signed certificate? Put a copy in your OS certificate bundle.